# how to close default https connection from rocketmq nameserver 9876

Tags: java, rocketmq

I encountered a problem!!!

step 1. RocketMq server run in the windows server.

step 2. browser open https://ip:9876  appear safety warning,
http://ip:9876 is ok
[image]

I'm just want close https, how can I do it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: NameServer by default listens for HTTP connections, not HTTPS, so you don't need to do anything. Just access the NameServer with http://ip:9876, as you've found that it works fine. There is nothing to close

Comment: @yahorbarkouski
Thinks! 
But still issues
I'm update the question  add one img describe the detail

Comment: when you try to access the httpS://ip:9876, your browser attempts to establish a secure connection, but since the server isn't set up for HTTPS, you receive a safety warning, and that's fine